# Volley JsonObjectRequest doesn't accept JsonObject as response

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I've been stock for a while and seems like Google volley isn't working as I expect.
I've a `JsonObject` request prepared as this:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject.put("auth-code", authCode);
    } catch (JSONException ignored) {
    }
    JsonObjectRequest response = new JsonObjectRequest(UrlController.getGoogleOauthSendAuthCodeMethod(), UrlController.getGoogleOauthSendAuthCodeUrl(), jsonObject.toString(), onSuccess, onError);  
 AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(response, "REGISTER_USER_GOOGLE_OAUTH");
```

It just sends google `auth-code` to my server and gets a jsonObject as response.

In response to that request I retrieve this:

```
{"data":{"user":
               {"name":"name lastname",
               "username":"someusername",
               "email":"email@gmail.com"},
         "token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjQxNDIsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL2FzaG9qYXNoLm1pbFwvYXBpXC92MVwvYXV0aFwvZ29vZ2xlIiwiaWF0IjoxNDUyNDY3NTQ4LCJleHAiOjE0NTI0NzExNDgsIm5iZiI6MTQ1MjQ2NzU0OCwianRpIjoiMTNhNjU0MjcwMmQ2MmE5MDA1YTgyZTlkZTM3YjQxNGQifQ.YfQaGuhVTYXPizdt2AX8C0RAObUNoqJp4rglZPOGW7s",
         "is_new_user":false
         }
}
```

But Volley always, enters onError section.
I have tested the server api, as it returns this data.

Some note-worthy thing:
When I return this json object, without checking the `auth-code` and just returning a random user from the database, the code enters the onResponse callback. I've logged the server, I got `auth-code` there too ,and retrieving response correctly.

So what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is the excpetion thrown in the onError callback? just log it and post it with your question.

Comment: I m not sure  about this because It doesn't appear in your code but, shouldn't you use "response" instead of "request" when adding it to the request queue?

Comment: @AnixPasBesoin The odd part is ``error.networkResponse`` is null!
So no status code or data I can get from there :(

Comment: @AnixPasBesoin That was a typo, since I had trimmed my code from several classes. tnx!

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason, Volley `time-out` request is 2.5 sec.
I was authenticating an `auth-code` which was taking more than that time.
To solve it use this code snippet for your Volley `Request`

```
     response.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(15000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

15000 is `requestTimeOut` in ms.